# replace data with regular expression, my expression regular is not functioned - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the text in the next way

if the text contains letters, it should replace with empty

if the text contains commas, you should replace with point

if the text contains points, it should replace with empty

I created the next

```
const a= 'C$ 8.572.121.247,04';
a.replace("C$","").split(".").join('').split(",").join('.')
```

The result is the next

> 8572121247.04

Hi,

I need to replace the text in the next way

if the text contains letters, it should replace with empty

if the text contains commas, you should replace with point

if the text contains points, it should replace with empty

I created the next

```
const a= 'C$ 8.572.121.247,04';
a.replace("C$","").split(".").join('').split(",").join('.')
```

The result is the next

> 8572121247.04

But i consider that it is not the better way, because it replaces too many times, also it can be a littler better, but i haven't finded the way

> someone can help me please to optimize the code

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: because the code is with typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use an alternation `[^0-9,]|(,)` and use replace with a callback function checking for the value of group 1.

```js
const a = 'C$ 8.572.121.247,04';
console.log(a.replace(/[^0-9,]|(,)/g, (_, g1) => g1 ? "." : ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` method which is more compact.

```js
const a = 'C$ 8.572.121.247,04';
console.log(a.replace(/[^0-9,]/ig, '').replace(/,/ig, '.'));
```

Comment: it is neccesary to use two replace, it is possible to use one?